# List compatibility programs in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, compatibility

My problem is as follows: about twice a day, my WiFi Internet connection is disconnected and the taskbar seems to have compatibility mode features on.  A minute later it returns to normal and the internet connection is restored.  Now, it's quite clear that some scheduled task causes it to happen.

Since the network issue starts exactly when the taskbar enters compatibility mode, I assume both are linked, that's why I'm looking for a way to list all the programs that have the following compatibility settings:

- Disable visual themes
- Disable desktop composition
- Disable display scaling on high DPI settings

Is there such way in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7352)

You would then install that and open the program called "Compatibility Administrator" and expand "Per User Compatibility Settings". Compatibility options that have been set by each user of the system will be listed here.

**Note:** the 32bit version of Compatibility Administrator is likely to show more information than the 64bit version. (I think the 64bit version doesn't show compatibility options for 32bit programs correctly).

Also in the "System Database" section there seems to be a list of preset compatibility options for some programs.

It might also be worth using Process Monitor in [System Internals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) and create a filter in it that only shows which programs are launching. Then when the taskbar goes into basic mode you can look at process monitor and see which process just started.

There also seems to be some compatibility options stored in this registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

But that seems to be a entirely different list to the one the application compatibility toolkit shows.

Comment: Thank you! one thing i did try was Process Monitor, but not in the way you suggested - will try

Comment: Yeh I think the filter you need to include is "Operation - is - Process Create"

Comment: I have included "Process Start" and "Process Exit" - will add yours as well.
Was going to write here that for this untill now it didn't happen again but it did happen about 5 minutes ago and... Process Monitor wasn't on - it was on almost each day. I will keep you posted.